# angular iterate over json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

So I have a json and I am trying to get all the stats for active users only.  when I try to do in a for loop something like this

```
for(var i=0; i < user.User.Stats.data.length; $i++;){
            return user.User.Stats[i].active === "1";    
}
```

it doesn't work ...however works fine without for loop as long as I am getting only one record

```
return user.User.Stats[i].active === "1";
```

here is my html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="user in _users | filter:isActive">
    {{user.User.userid}}
</div>
</div>
```

here is my js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.isActive = function(user) {
       // for(var i=0; i < user.User.Stats.data.length; $i++;){
            return user.User.Stats[0].active === "1";    
       // }

    };

    $scope._users = [
        {
        "User": {
            "userid": "19571",
            "status": "7",
            "active": "1",
            "lastlogin": "1339759025307",
            "Stats": [
                {
                "active": "1",
                "catid": "10918",
                "typeid": "71",
                "Credits": [
                    {
                    "content": "917,65",
                    "active": "1",
                    "type": "C7"},
                {
                    "content": "125,65",
                    "active": "1",
                    "type": "B2"}
                ]},
                                {
                "active": "1",
                "catid": "10918",
                "typeid": "71",
                "Credits": [
                    {
                    "content": "917,65",
                    "active": "1",
                    "type": "C7"},
                {
                    "content": "125,65",
                    "active": "1",
                    "type": "B2"}
                ]}
            ]
        }}];
}
```

here is a demo link http://jsfiddle.net/4kzzy/174/

Comment: the syntax of your for loop is wrong. By the way, you can also use angular.forEach instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing complicated, it’s just that your syntax is wrong.

The for loop needs to be written like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < user.User.Stats.length; i++)
```

I.e. without the superfluous `$`, without the superfluous `;`, and also there is no `data` inside `Stats`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/4kzzy/176/

Also note you could use [`angular.forEach`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach) instead.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure whether it is suitable solution for your problem, but if you want to display only active users, try this design:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="user in _users | filter:{User.active:1}">
        {{user.User.userid}}
</div>
</div>
```

Show:
19571

http://jsfiddle.net/Jd2Hw/

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's pretty obvious that it won't work, as there is no variable called `data` in the `user.User.Stats` path. It seems like there is a part of your business logic missing. When users should be filtered out? When they have no `Stats`, or all cells in `Stats` array have records with `active === 1` ? 
To see all the cells in `Stats` array the proper syntax would be:

```
for(var i=0; i < user.User.Stats.length; $i++;){
    var singleCell = user.User.Stats[i];
    // singleCell.active === "1";    
}
```