# Looping json data using AngularJS in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to fetch records via ajax and displaying using AngularJS.
But **my code even not invoking controller action**.

I am trying this code..

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="result in products">
    {{result.ProductName}}
</div>
</div>
```

Ajax :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Products/Get/",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
      // Success message
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
      $scope.products = data;
    },
    error: function () {
      // Fail message
    },
  });
}
```

I am using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987604/angular-iterate-over-json) to make it work.

Comment: You don't have controller `MyCtrl`

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong.
You should use angularJS's controller directive to invoke services to consume json data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {  
        $http.get('/Products/Get/').success(function (data) {  
            $scope.products = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I had written an article few days ago on the same.
You can go through [here](http://www.mitracircle.com/post/8/iterate-json-data-using-angularjs-in-mvc). This might be helpful.

Comment: Since `success` is *deprecated* you should use `then` instead of `success`.

Answer (score 0):

you need declare `module` name in angularjs , and dont forget to add module name in you body or html tag..like this `<body data-ng-app="app">` and then Try like this :

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$http){

bindData();
function bindData(
    // it will be nice, if this code your separate to file service...    
    $http.get('/Products/Get').success(function (callBack) {  
            $scope.products = callBack.data;
    });
);
});

</script>
```

and Best Implementation like This :

```
// in controller, injected you service name like this..
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$http ,myServices){

bindData();
function bindData(
  var promiseGet = myServices.GetAll();
  promiseGet.then(function(callBack){ // success
    $scope.products = callBack.data;

   }     
 ,function(error){ // error
     console.log(error);
   });
 );
```

});

```
app.service('myServices',function($http){
var vm = this;
vm.GetAll = function(){
         return $http.get('/Products/Get');
     }
});
```

and type not `POST`, if you want to Get data in ajax function..