# how can I loop through returned Resource object data using angular.forEach loop in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, foreach

I came across a similar [scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987604/angular-iterate-over-json), but my attempts failed because undefined was always returned and kept on getting error after error in the console.

The data is retrieved from the openweathermap API using the angular $resource factory. I understand that i can target and get some of the data i need in the view using ng-repeat but what I also want to break down this data in the controller and access some of the keys and values. When I `console.log($scope.weatherResult)` variable that holds the data retrieved from the api I get a Resource object in the console.

How can I go about looping through this object to retrieve the data I need. Its basically objects within objects within arrays. In the view ng-repeat does wonders to get this data but in the controller I don't know how to retrieve it. For example if I `console.log($scope.weatherResult.city)` or `console.log($scope.weatherResult.list)` the result in the console is always undefined.

Now the data I want to retrieve is within the list array - two days worth of data, but the first object list[0].temp has temperature figures, I want to calculate the sum of those figures and divide it and get the average so I can store it in another variable in the controller and output it in the view.

I'm not sure if im taking a long route here, but i've been in similar situations before but managed to get away with it using the ng-repeat in the view. I need to learn how to do this.

Is it possible to loop through the resource object using `angular.forEach()` function and get the data in the temp object? I have attached an image for reference. I am still learning and gaining experience with JavaScript and angular in particular.

[image: Angular Resource loop]

Comment: In the controller, if `$resource('/api/weather/city/Chicago', function(response){$scope.weatherResult = response.data.weatherResult})`  The weatherResult from the callback should be accessible.  I think you are trying to return it from the Resource object without a callback.  i.e. `$scope.weatherResult = $resource('/api/weather/city/Chicago');  console.log($scope.weatherResult.city);`.  *This won't work as is the case with promises*.  Please *do* always refer to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: You want to get the data in the temp object using forEach or do you want to add the temperatures in temp using forEach?

Comment: @ThatBird retrieve the data from the temp object and have it pushed into a variable like so $scope.temperature = [13.47, 12.33, 13.47, 10.04, 10.04, 10.07].

Comment: @Manesh the callback is there, here is a snippet. `$resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", {
    callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get: { method: "JSONP"}});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.temp = []
angular.forEach(list[0].temp, function(value,key){
  $scope.temp.push(value);
})
```

See if this helps you.