# Accessing nested json using ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I have json which is nested i have tried to access nested part using ngFor but getting issue

[Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InMEm.png)

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="mb-4 z-depth" *ngFor="let job of moduleData.courses">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header collapsedHeight="*" expandedHeight="*">
        <div class="row p-2 w-100">
          <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
            <span class="mat-body-2">Module Id</span>
            <p class="mat-body">{{ job.modules[0].id}}</p><br>
          </div>
        </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="row p-2 w-100">
        <a href="{{job.modules[0].content[0].media_url}}">
          <span class="mat-body-2">1. {{job.modules[0].content[0].name}}</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: can you please share JSON?

Comment: Please share json data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular iterate over json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987604/angular-iterate-over-json)

Comment: Make sure that `moduleData.courses` actually has some data in it and it is accessible. `console.log()` it in your component.

Answer (score 2):

Using this code you can access nested json object value.it will helps you.

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="mb-4 z-depth" *ngFor="let job of moduleData.courses">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header collapsedHeight="*" expandedHeight="*"  *ngFor="let modules of job.modules">
        <div class="row p-2 w-100">
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
                <span class="mat-body-2">Module Id</span>
                <p class="mat-body">{{ modules.id}}</p><br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="row p-2 w-100" *ngFor="let mediaUrl of modules.content">
                <a href="{{mediaUrl.media_url}}">
                    <span class="mat-body-2">1. {{mediaUrl.name}}</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This won't work i guess beacuse my media url will not be shown in panel header .It should work like online courses platform when you click the module it will show videos under that module